# "Inspect" vs. "control"

Tags: word-choice, differences, verbs, nuance

Which of *inspect* or *control* is more appropriate when referring to action checking the operational state of something?

Context: Workers are checking the operational state of a billboard with regards to its cleanliness, lighting, etc. Their sole job is to report their findings, they are not required to act on their findings.

Is the difference just cosmetic for my context, or is there some subtle difference in meaning between using *inspect* and *control*?

Comment: What is your context? It's hard to answer the first part of your question without knowing. Also, did you look up each of these words in a dictionary? If not, perhaps you should start there. On the other hand, if you've already checked a dictionary, perhaps you should share your findings here, so we need not scurry to consult our dictionaries, lest we post something erroneous.

Comment: I thought the context is clear from the question. Refining it a bit more, workers are checking the operational state of billboards (wrt  lighting, cleanliness of the glass, etc.)

Comment: An inspector looks; a controller acts. If they are authorized to change what they're inspecting, and they **do** occasionally or frequently change it, they can be said to _control_ it. But if they are not authorized to do anything more than look, measure, and report, they are not controlling it. And if they have the authority but never use it, something else is going on.

Comment: @Kaan: "something" doesn't make for very clear context. "Something" could be an assembly line, an oil pan, a dog, a fish, an airplane, or a computer program.

Comment: @J.R. thanks for the explanation. I'm editing the question with that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are just looking and reporting, then *inspect* would be the right choice.

If they are also making repairs, adjustments, cleaning, etc, this might be termed *maintain*, or maybe specified more precisely.

*Control* would more usually describe the continuous adjustment of the object's state during normal operation.

However, in some other languages, the equivalent of *control* is used to mean what we call *inspect*, so take care if your document is to be read by people from other language cultures.